# How to increase space above graph to make room for a title in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a graph but when I try to make a title it gets smushed with the x-axis label.  I would like to put the title above the axis but when I try to resize the graph with the dots it resize the graph area, leaving no additional white-space for chart elements.

[Chart title cannot be moved above x-axis.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRtlO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter space in Title as shown in the following picture：

[image]